# How can I change the graph interval in Live Metrics Stream

Tags: azure-application-insights, live-streaming

The current interval of 1 second and max of 60 seconds is too small and issues may be missed.

When viewing the live metrics stream page of Application Insights the interval on all graphs are 1 second, and it only goes up to 60 seconds. I am trying to use this as a monitoring page to keep an eye on recently released or updated function apps. For this I need to be able to change the interval to view more data at once without having to keep watch on it. Right now if we don't keep watch on it every minute we may miss something important.

I have searched the Microsoft documentation, the git repository, stackoverflow, and various other sites trying to find my answer but the only thing I found was from over 4 years ago and I would hope that this has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Live Metrics Stream allows to peek at what's going one right now with 1 second resolution. But it doesn't persist data anywhere. So, data is only stored in UX (browser) and right now only for 60 seconds.

For bigger intervals it might make sense to refer to other Application Insights experiences (including Analytics).